# Проверьте гипотезу о том, что рост описывается экспоненциальной функцией

Tags: python, python-3.x, синтаксический-анализ, анализ-данных

Передо мной стоит стоит следующая задача "Взять исходные данные о числе заболевших COVI за 8.02.2020 по 20.03.2020. Проверьте гипотезу о том, что рост описывается экспоненциальной функцией. Уровень значимости 5%". Для этого я построил два графика, один - график регрессии, а второй фактический(по исходным данным), нашел среднеквадратичное отклонение. Но вот, как проверить гипотезу ума не приложу.

Функция моего экспоненциального роста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, что для проверки нужно найти p значение, но как его следует найти в моем случие я не знаю. Гугл так и не ответил на мой вопрос(возможно я не правильно искал). Я попробывал разобраться в этом параметре(я про р) с помощю книги Джоэля Граса, но я так и не понял, как решить мою задачу. Подскажите, как можно проверить данную гипотезу.

Гафики:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math as m

infected = [75138, 75670, 76202, 77274, 78633, 78990, 79774, 80419, 81383, 82790, 84158, 86572, 88374, 90301, 92138,
            95088, 97760, 101611, 105865, 109751, 113921, 119125, 126258, 135784, 141401, 153963, 163611, 181831,
            194651, 218397, 246305, 275978]  

n = len(infected)
rho = [i for i in range(n)]
gamma_p = []

for g_i in infected:
    gamma_p.append(m.log(g_i))

a = 0
B1 = 0
B2 = 0
B3 = 0
B4 = 0

for i in range(n):
    B1 = B1 + rho[i] * gamma_p[i]
    B3 = B3 + rho[i] ** 2
    for j in range(n):
        B2 = B2 + rho[i] * gamma_p[j] / len(rho)
        B4 = B4 + rho[i] * rho[j] / len(rho)
b = (B1 - B2) / (B3 - B4)

for i in range(n):
    a = a + (gamma_p[i] - b * rho[i]) / len(rho)
print("a =", m.exp(a), " b =", b)

g = []
for r_i in rho:
    g.append(m.exp(a) * m.exp(b * r_i))

plt.plot(rho, infected, 'rx', label='Fact')
plt.plot(rho, g, 'b-', label='Regression')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

"""Среднеквадратичное отклонение"""
ar = 0
for i in range(n):
    ar += infected[i]
ar /= n

dis = 0
print("Среднеквадратичное отклонение")
for i in range(n):
    dis += (g[i] - ar)**2

print(m.sqrt(dis/(n - 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

А откуда взялась задача? Как-то там все намешано. Какие p-value, какой уровень значимости?

Я так понимаю, задача стоит просто - построить регрессионную модель вашей кривой. Если вы предполагаете экспоненциальный рост, то обычно линеаризуют модель, беря логарифм от левой и правой части уравнения. Если ваша догадка верна, то полученная зависимость должна оказаться почти линейной. Строите ее регрессионную модель, проверяете ее адекватность, например посчитав коэффициент детерминации. Потом возвращаетесь к исходной модели выполняя потенцирование. p-value могут возникнуть разве что при оценке параметров регрессионной модели.